# Finding a C style comment block (/* */) but not those inside of a string using regex?

Tags: java, c, regex, comments

My problem is that I have a program that goes through a standard C file (here I just used a text file). I was able to get it to recognize comments, however I can't get it to not recognized comment blocks in a string. So for example:

```
printf("This should be counted as a comment: /* */");
```

However, it says that since if found the /* */ it's true. The regex pattern I am using

```
((['"])(?:(?!\2|\\).|\\.)*\2)|\/\/[^\n]*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*(?!\/))*\*\/
```

Just need to get it to include double quoted strings.

Comment: regular expression might not be the right tool for you

Comment: antlr has a C grammar already worked out: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions can't recognize context sensitive (Typ-1) languages. They can only be used to match Typ-3 languages.
[Chomsky-Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#Type-2_grammars)

Since your 'language' you are trying to match is not regular, you can not use regular expressions for this problem.

I would advise you to use a different approach. Like parsing the input by hand.
Maybe for small parts of the whole parsing regex is useful.